# In Godot 3.2.1 stable beta, in the 2D sprite shaders, how do I import a new PNG to test out those shaders?

Tags: 2d, shaders, sprites, godot

[image]

I am using Godot 3.2.1. on Steam on Linux Mint. How do I take a pixel art image I've made and import it for using in Godot? I couldn't find it under Project.

Comment: Does [the Godot documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/getting_started/workflow/assets/import_process.html) on [importing image assets](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/getting_started/workflow/assets/importing_images.html) not cover your use case?

Comment: Apparently you have to put in the folder, you can't do it through the program. I did read the docs. I just didn't understand them/

Comment: Ah, like it says in the second paragraph of the first link: "Simply drop your assets (image files, scenes, audio files, fonts, etc) directly in the project folder (copy them manually with your OS file explorer)." If you've solved your problem, please feel free to post an Answer explaining it to others who might run into similar trouble.